# Determine which of the following words could end the statement above and make it a true proposition.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Consider the statement: Let $f:A \to B$ be a function. Then $\forall C \subseteq A, f^{-1}(f(C))=C \iff f$ is a(n)

- surjection
- injection
- bijection

($\Rightarrow$) Let $x \in f^{-1}(f(C))$. Then $f(x) \in f(C)$. This means that $\exists x \in C \ni f(x) \in B$. Suppose $x \notin C$, then $\exists y \in C \ni x \ne y$ and $f(x)=f(y)$. But this means that $f$ is not injective; however, this is impossible since that would imply that $f^{-1}(f(C)) \nsubseteq C$. Thus $f$ must be an injection, and hence $x \in C$. And since $x$ is an arbitrarily chosen element of $f^{-1}(f(C))$, it follows that $f^{-1}(f(C)) \subseteq C$.

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose $f$ is an injection. Then $f(x)=f(y) \Rightarrow x=y$. Let $x \in C$. As $C \subseteq f^{-1}(f(C))$, then $x \in f^{-1}(f(C))$. Since $x$ is an arbitrarily chosen element of $C$, it follows that $C \subseteq f^{-1}(f(C))$.

Therefore, $f^{-1}(f(C))=C \iff f$ is an injection.

I'm not sure this is correct. Any help would be much appreciated!

**Edit**

($\Rightarrow$) Suppose $f^{-1}(f(C))=C$. Then $x \in f^{-1}(f(C)) \Rightarrow x \in C$, so $f(x) \in f(C)$. This means that $\exists x \in C \ni f(x)=b \in B$. Suppose $x \notin C$ whenever $x \in f^{-1}(f(C))$. Then $\exists y \in C \ni x \ne y$ and $f(x)=f(y)$. But this means that $f$ is not injective; however, this is impossible since that would imply that $f^{-1}(f(C)) \nsubseteq C$. Therefore, $f^{-1}(f(C)) = C \Rightarrow f$ is an injection.

I'm not sure if this is correct and I can't figure out how to use injection for ($\Leftarrow$).

Comment: In ($\Rightarrow$), I can't make sense of $\exists x \in C \ni f(x) \in B$. And in ($\Leftarrow$), you never use the fact that $f$ is an injection, as far as I can see; and you reach the conclusion $C \subseteq f^{-1}(f(C))$, which is not what you need (in fact it was your starting point). Perhaps this last mistake is just a typo? Please clarify these steps.

Comment: @TonyK That’s right. I was thinking that we don’t need the fact that $f$ is an injection for ($\Leftarrow$)? So would it be correct to remove that assumption? But since this is an if and only if statement aren’t we required to use it?

Comment: @TonyK in ($\Rightarrow$), I used the fact that $f(X)=\{b \in B|\exists x \in X \ni b=f(x)\} 
 $if $f: A \to B$ and $X \subseteq A$.

Comment: Karam, what does the symbol $\ni$ mean, in your opinion?